# Java Palindrome assignment - boolean always returns False value

Tags: java, boolean, palindrome

everyone. I am having issues with an assignment for my Java programming class and would like your opinion on it.

The assignment for the method *pA* is to create a method using only *String* and *Character* methods. As such, I have programmed the following methods and when I attempt to call the method *pA*, it automatically returns a false value. I am thinking there may be something wrong with my for loop but as I am not sure, I figured I would ask on here to see what you have to say.

Thank you in advance, for your time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates Scanner object to take user input

    String pal; //String to contain user input

    boolean test = false; //boolean to test if user input is a palindrome.

    System.out.println("This program determines if your input is a palindrome!");
    System.out.println("Please enter your input to see if it's a palindrome.");
            pal = keyboard.nextLine();

    pA(pal, test);
    if (test == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have a palindrome!");
    }
    else if (test == false)
    {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately, you do not have a palindrome.");
    }

}

public static boolean pA(String pal, boolean test) //Part A of Assignment 7.
{
    int l = pal.length(); //integer to contain length of string
    int i; //Loop control variable
    test = false;

    for (i = 0; i < l/2; i++) //for loop that tests to see if input is a palindrome.
    {
        if (pal.charAt(i) == pal.charAt(l-i-1)) //Compares character at point i with respective character at the other end of the string.
        {   
            test = true; //Sets boolean variable to true if the if statement yields true.
        } else 
            test = false; //Otherwise, a false value is returned.
             break;
    }
    return test; //Return statement for boolean variable
} //End pA
```

From here, when I attempt to Run the program, I get the following message when using the input "tubbut":

run:

This program determines if your input is a palindrome!

Please enter your input to see if it's a palindrome.

tubbut

Unfortunately, you do not have a palindrome.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Answer (score 4):

You are ignoring the result of your call to the `pA` method, so the `test` variable in `main` is unchanged.  Also, there is no reason to pass in `test` to `pA`, because then `pA` only has a copy of the value anyway.

In main, try

```
test = pA(pal);
```

And in `pA`, remove the `test` parameter; you can make it a local variable.

```
public static boolean pA(String pal) //Part A of Assignment 7.
{
   int l = pal.length(); //integer to contain length of string
   int i; //Loop control variable
   boolean test = false;  // *** Now it's a local variable
   // Rest of method is here.
}
```

Additionally, in `main`, `test` is already `boolean`, so you don't need to compare it against `true` or `false`.  You can replace

```
if (test == true)
{
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You have a palindrome!");
}
else if (test == false)
{
    System.out.println("Unfortunately, you do not have a palindrome.");
}
```

with

```
if (test)
{
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You have a palindrome!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Unfortunately, you do not have a palindrome.");
}
```